# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'questionText')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I get an error message that my "questionText" could not be read or is not defined. The first code is where I use "questionText" and the second code is where I want to drag it. Did I do something wrong that he can't read "questionText"? If you need anything else just write. I need to take away some of the code because StackOverflow doesn't want that much code :( .

```
import React from 'react'
import Card from './Card'

import "./Question.css"

const Question = ({
  questionIndex,
  setQuestionIndex,
  questions,
  setShowQuestionsPagePop,
  setShowFinalPage,
  score,
  setScore,
}) => {
  const handleClick = (isCorrect) => {
    if (questionIndex < 9) {
      if (isCorrect) {
        setScore((score) => score += 100);
      }

      setQuestionIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex + 1);
    } else {
      if (isCorrect) {
        setScore((score) => (score += 100));
      }

      setShowQuestionsPagePop(false);
      setShowFinalPage(true);
    }
  };


  return (
    <Card>
      <h1 className="question">{questions[questionIndex].questionText}</h1>

      <div className="answers">
        {questions[questionIndex].answers.map((answer, index) => (
          <div 
            className="answer"
            key={index}
            onClick={() => handleClick(answer.correctAnswer)}
          >
            <p>{answer.answerText}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </Card>
  )
}

export default Question
```

```
export const questions = [
    {
      questionText: "How long is an Olympic swimming pool (in meters)",
      answers: [
        {
          answerText: "50",
          correctAnswer: true,
        },
        {
          answerText: "60",
          correctAnswer: false,
        },
        {
          answerText: "75",
          correctAnswer: false,
        },
        {
          answerText: "100",
          correctAnswer: false,
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

Comment: Please share how the question component is being used

Comment: Stick a break point in somewhere and inspect `questions[questionIndex].questionText` see what it is, perhaps it is null, if you're tyring to access this before its loaded you can fix this by surrounding your component with { questions && <Card...> ... </Card>} so that its only tries to render when the data is loaded

Comment: perhaps questions && questions.length && questions[questionIndex].questionText.map(... so that it will only map them when they exist and have a length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), this enables you to read a property of an object if it's present, otherwise will return `undefined` so your code will not break, try something like:

```js
<h1 className="question">{questions[questionIndex]?.questionText}</h1>
```

Another option is to manually check if the property is present and has a value so you could do something like:

```js
<h1 className="question">{questions && questions[questionIndex] && question[index].questionText && questions[questionIndex].questionText}</h1>
```

but it's a very messy code so I would use the first one.

Comment: It worked thank you! But now I get another error xD